# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /registeruser.jsp(35,0) Unterminated &lt;form:form tag

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Hi guys Just needed a little help. While using form tag i am getting error 'org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /registeruser.jsp(35,0) Unterminated <form:form tag'

Below is my jsp and i have all required jar files. I have edited and made it clear :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="sec"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Test Registration</title>
</head>

<body>

<h5> Registration Page</h5>


<form:form id = "RegisterForm" action = "/submitRegistration" method = "POST" commandName= "register_form">

<table>

<tr><td>FirstName</td></tr>


<form:input path="register_form.firstName" size="30"/>

<tr><td>LastName</td></tr>

<form:input path="register_form.LasttName" size="30"/>

<tr><td>Email Address</td></tr>

<form:input path="register_form.EmailAddress" size="30"/>

<tr><td>Address</td></tr>

<form:input path="register_form.Address" size="30"/>

<tr><td>Phone</td></tr>

<form:input path="register_form.Phone" size="30"/>

<tr><td><input type = "submit" value = "Submit Registration"></td></tr>

</table>

</form:form>

</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone please help me out ?

Comment: You have an unclosed `<tr>` and `<td>` on the first row.  It would be easier to spot if you used some better formatting.

Comment: Your `<form:input` elements are between `<tr>` tags. Which renders invalid html.

Comment: I tried by closing tr tag its still giving same error

Comment: @M.Deinum You have all sorts of problems with your html nesting.  Use some proper tabbing and they are easy to spot.

Comment: Why would I have problems... I guess you meant @user3541375...

Comment: I have edited it. Please help me now